# iTerm2 how to get autocomplete through tab key

Tags: iterm

In my terminal I can press tab key to autocomplete dir names etc but I can't do this in iTerm2. Is there any way to do that in iterm2? I'm using bash.

I know `cmd ;` shows autocomplete but I'd like to use tab key to get the behavior from the built in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866682/how-to-enable-autocomplete-in-iterm2).

*Note, the answer you're after is not the accepted one. It's one below it.*